# Дублирование Non static методов

Tags: java, jvm

Хотел узнать дублируется ли non static  методы в объектах, если создать 1000 объектов получается в каждом объекте будет копия этого метода

Comment: разумеется ничего не дублируется. Иначе никаких методов не напасешься на каждый экземпляр

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код методов классов (как статичных, так и нестатичных) всегда* хранится в единственном экземпляре вне зависимости от количества созданных объектов. Для каждого объекта выделяется память только под данные - значение полей класса.

`*` Это утверждение может быть неверным, если код одного и того же класса загружен несколькими classloader'ами. В этом случае код дублируется, но классы, загруженные разными classloader'ами, считаются разными, даже если они были загружены из одного и того же .class-файла.